# Getting unique device ID in Win8 app

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1

I need to get an unique device identifier in Windows 8 application. I have few applications and I need to determine device ID that have one or more apps installed (e.g. a bonus for a gamer installing other game in the series). Using following methods provides me with per-app IDs which won't tell me that device have some other apps installed.

I've tried three different approaches but they all return different UDIDs on the same PC.

1) This was used before, since I needed unique id per app, now I need UDID, so it's predictably doesn't work for me:

```
GUID g;
std::string ret;
CoCreateGuid(&g);
Platform::Guid pg(g);
std::string udid = WStringToUTF8(pg.ToString()->Data());
```

2) I've tried EasClienDeviceInformation, which was suggested as a sure thing, but got different results for 2 apps on the same PC:

```
EasClientDeviceInformation^ info = ref new EasClientDeviceInformation;
ret = WStringToUTF8(info->Id.ToString()->Data());
```

3) And I've tried the commonly used way to get ASHWID, without any hope and it obviously shown different UDIDs:

```
auto token = Windows::System::Profile::HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken(nullptr);
ret = WStringToUTF8(Windows::Security::Cryptography::CryptographicBuffer::EncodeToBase64String(token->Id)->Data());
_RPT1(_CRT_WARN, "TOKEN UDID IS %s \n", ret.c_str());
```

I know only about one option and it's to use MAC-address, but I'm not sure if it's a valid option. Users can have a PC where MAC-address could be changed or duplicated (I've heard of batches of chinese network adapters having the same address), or have a device without a network whatsoever (e.g. use a PC without a network adapter and connect to the internet using USB dongles).

So the questions are:

1. Did I do everything right, or I made a mistake that caused my examples to return wrong UDIDs?
2. Am I right to assume that MAC-address is the only viable way to get a trutfully unique per-device identifier? I could've been inattentive and missed some obvious way.
3. Am I wrong in my assumptions of MAC-address identification insecurities like those I've described above?

---

UPD: I also would like to know the right way for WP8, while we're on it.

Comment: Are you trying to uniquely identify each installed system?  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to identify and why.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: @rrirower I have few applications and I need to determine device ID that have one or more apps installed (e.g. a bonus for a gamer installing other game in the series). (Updated description)

Comment: Have you looked into using Windows Management Instrumentation?  It contains lots of "management" information that should provide a unique identifier.

Comment: @rrirower No, I haven't. I shall look into that, thank you.

Comment: @rrirower Currently there is no interface to WMI from Windows Store apps. And Metro apps cannot access this information: